# How to specify boolean value in argument to external command?

Tags: command-line, options

The man page for `txt2html` says:

```
       --make_links
           Should we try to build links?  If this is false, then the links dictionaries are not consulted and only structural text-to-HTML conversion is
           done.  (default: true)
```

I want to set this to false. How do I do this? I could not find this information, and have tried several guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `txt2html` manual](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/txt2html.1p.html) also says

> Boolean options can be negated by preceding them with `no` [...]

The manual then refers to the Perl package `Getopt::Long`.  In *its* manual, one may read the following about boolean options:

> The option does not take an argument and may be negated by prefixing it with
> `no` or `no-`. [...]

This means that to invert the sense of the `--make-links` option, use `--no-make-links` or `--nomake-links`.

Comment: So it does! It was a long man page and I didn't think to search for "boolean" in it. My bad. To myself: RTFM (more). Thank you!